# Function in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using the following formula at a lot of places inside an xsl file.

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($Value div 1000000, '##.##')" />
```

Is there anyway I can create a function so I can keep the logic at one place and reuse it as per below example?

Example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ConvertToMillionAndFormatNumber($Value)" />
```

Comment: Depending on the context you might need or not a function. For example, you could use template rules to match text nodes. As for using user defined functions, in XSLT 1.0 you need the [extension function mechanism](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#section-Extension-Functions). There are several questions and answers for each specific XSLT processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no custom functions in XSLT 1.0 (unless your processor happens to support them as an extension), but you can use a named template:

```
<xsl:template name="ConvertToMillionAndFormatNumber">
    <xsl:param name="Value" />
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($Value div 1000000, '##.##')" />
</xsl:template>
```

and call it as:

```
<xsl:call-template name="ConvertToMillionAndFormatNumber">
    <xsl:with-param name="Value" select="your-value-here"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give a try.  Do you know how can I check version of my XSLT?

Comment: @developer See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033#25245033